# Chat messages from Dialogflow don't appear in Slack

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, slack

I'm creating a bot with Dialogflow. It's quite straigtforward, and it worked on Telegram in no time. But things complicated when trying to integrate Dialogflow with Slack.

My bot is able to read direct messages from Slack, and I'm sure of it because the messages from Slack appear in the `History` section of Dialogflow. Good news there. In the same screen, I can see that Dialogflow answered all the messages Slack sent to it. But sadly, those answers don't appear in Slack.

By the way, just to confuse me more, the Dialogflow's test bot works flawlessly with Slack, publishing there with no issue. So, it's not anything related with the common values you have to copy from Slack and paste to Dialogflow to enable the integration.

It seems that my bot on Slack misses some kind of permission of the `OAuth & Permissions` screen, but I've tried some of theme, and I can't find the good one. Right now I'm using `bot`, `chat:write:bot`, `im:write`, and `channels:read`. I guess that only the two first ones are needed, but I'm totally lost and tried adding permissions with no reason. And then, I wrote this post.

Is there someone who has a simple bot that sends messages in direct messages on Slack? What are the needed permissions?

Comment: have you followed the instructions here?: https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/slack

Comment: Can you post your code thus far?

Comment: @matthewayne totally. I did it twice...

Comment: @S.Dwyer there is no code to show. I mean, everything is done via DialogFlow and Slack's dashboards. No programming code at all.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, it's quite easy to solve: just go on *Manage Distribution* in your bot's Slack API panel and click on the "Add to Slack" button.

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

Under OAuth & Permissions, add "chat:write" to OAuth Scope. That will allow your bot to send messages to other users.